# Taking Different Functions for Different Columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've the following dataset.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A',
                         'B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
                   'ColA': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
                         1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'ColB': np.random.randint(0,100,20),
                   'ColC': np.random.randint(0,100,20)})
```

I want to summarize columns `ColA`,`ColB`, and `ColC` by column `x`. But the summarization functions for each column are different; `ColA` is `max` and columns `ColB` and `ColC` are `mean`. My expected output is the following:

```
summarization = df.groupby('x').agg({'ColA':'max', 'ColB':'mean', 'ColC':'mean'})
print(summarization)

ColA  ColB  ColC
x                  
A    10  52.5  54.9
B    10  64.1  51.0
```

The challenge here is column names (`ColB` & `ColC` are dynamic). Also, instead of 2 columns I can have 3 columns or 1 column for which I need `mean` (or `max`). So, I need to combine few columns together for taking `mean` or `max`.

The ideal solution would be if I could do something like this:

```
df.groupby('x').agg({'ColA':'max', ['ColB','ColC']:'mean'})
```

But unfortunately `agg` function does not have this functionality.

Comment: Will you please show a sample dataframe containing your expected output? But first, run `np.random.seed(0)` so that we both get the same random values :)

Comment: The output is exactly same as your answer. But the problem is column names (`ColB` & `ColC` are dynamic). Also, instead of 2 columns I can have 3 or 1 column for which I need `mean`.  So, I need to combine few columns together for taking `mean` or `max`.

Comment: I don't get the issue. OK, the columns are dynamic but how do you define which gets which aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, `agg` doesn't support using lists to determine which columns to apply an aggregation to, and `dict`s don't support `list`s as keys. If you use some list-comprehension magic you can, though:

```
aggs = [
    ('ColA', 'max'),
    (df.columns[2:], 'mean'),
]

aggs = dict(item for k,v in aggs for item in (((k,v),) if isinstance(k, str) else [(item,v) for item in k]))

summarization = df.groupby('x').agg(aggs)
```

Output:

```
>>> summarization
   ColA  ColB  ColC
x                  
A    10  49.1  52.8
B    10  53.1  49.9
```